# ANTLR: parse NULL as a function name and a parameter

Tags: java, antlr4

I would like to be able to use 'NULL' as both a *parameter* (the value *null*) and a *function name* in my grammar. See this reduced example :

```
grammar test;

expr
  : value # valueExpr
  | FUNCTION_NAME '(' (expr (',' expr)* )* ')' # functionExpr
  ;


value
  : INT
  | 'NULL'
  ;

FUNCTION_NAME
  : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*
  ;


INT: [0-9]+;
```

Now, trying to parse:

```
NULL( 1 )
```

Results in the parse tree failing because it parses NULL as a value, and not a function name.

Ideally, I should even be able to parse `NULL(NULL)`..

Can you tell me if this is possible, and if yes, how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

That `'NULL'` string in your grammar defines an implicit token type, it's equivalent to adding something along this:

```
NULL: 'NULL';
```

At the start of the lexer rules. When a token matches several lexer rules, the first one is used, so in your grammar the implicit rule get priority, and you get a token of type `'NULL'`.

A simple solution would be to introduce a parser rule for function names, something like this:

```
function_name: FUNCTION_NAME | 'NULL';
```

and then use that in your `expr` rule. But that seems brittle, if `NULL` is not intended to be a keyword in your grammar. There are other solution to this, but I'm not quite sure what to advise since I don't know how you expect your grammar to expand.

But another solution could be to rename `FUNCTION_NAME` to `NAME`, get rid of the `'NAME'` token type, and rewrite `expr` like that:

```
expr
  : value # valueExpr
  | NAME '(' (expr (',' expr)* )* ')' # functionExpr
  | {_input.LT(1).getText().equals("NULL")}? NAME # nullExpr
  ;
```

A semantic predicate takes care of the name comparison here.