# ANTLR 4 building parse tree incorrectly

Tags: antlr4

I'm making a grammar for a subset of SQL, which I've pasted below:

```
grammar Sql;

sel_stmt : SEL QUANT? col_list FROM tab_list;
as_stmt : 'as' ID;
col_list : '*' | col_spec (',' col_spec | ',' col_group)*;
    col_spec : (ID | ID '.' ID) as_stmt?;
    col_group : ID '.' '*';
tab_list : (tab_spec | join_tab) (',' tab_spec | ',' join_tab)*;
tab_spec : (ID | sub_query) as_stmt?;
sub_query : '(' sel_stmt ')';

join_tab : tab_spec (join_type? 'join' tab_spec 'on' cond_list)+;
    join_type : 'inner' | 'full' | 'left' | 'right';
cond_list : cond_term (BOOL_OP cond_term)*;
cond_term : col_spec (COMP_OP val | between | like);
    val : INT | FLT | SQ_STR | DQ_STR;
    between : ('not')? 'between' val 'and' val;
    like : ('not')? 'like' (SQ_STR | DQ_STR);

WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n')+ -> skip;
INT : ('0'..'9')+;
FLT : INT '.' INT;
SQ_STR : '\'' ~('\\'|'\'')* '\'';
DQ_STR : '"' ~('\\'|'"')* '"';
BOOL_OP : ',' | 'or' | 'and';
COMP_OP : '=' | '<>' | '<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=';

SEL : 'select' | 'SELECT';
QUANT: 'distinct' | 'DISTINCT' | 'all' | 'ALL';
FROM: 'from' | 'FROM';
ID : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' | '0'..'9')*;
```

The input I'm testing is `select distinct test.col1 as col, test2.* from test join test2 on col='something', test2.col1=1.4`. The output parse tree matches the last appearance of test2 as a  and thus doesn't know what to do with the rest of the input. The comma before the last 'test2' token is made a child of the  node, when it should be a child of .

My question is what is going on behind the scenes to cause this?

Comment: Incidentally, that last part of the example does not appear to me as being valid ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, ANTLR does not like it when you use a literal symbol as a token and have it be part of another token. In my case, the comma token was both used as a literal token and as part of the BOOL_OP token.

A future question may be how ANTLR disambiguates when the same symbol is used as parts of different tokens that apply only under specific scopes. However, this question is answered for now.

Comment: This is a very classic mistake to make with ANTLR - ambiguous lexer rules. You need to know how ANTLR will disambiguate (implicit token types, then grammar order). I've answered similar question many times, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36619004/3764814), it's similar to your issue.